Unable to Retrieve Current Ad Spend Data from Meta Ad Accounts via Graph API
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to retrieve the current ad spend for our ad accounts on Meta (formerly Facebook) using the Graph API. The goal is to integrate this data into an external dashboard for better monitoring and analysis.
Here's the endpoint I'm using:
https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/act_<ad_acc_id>/insights?level=ad&date_preset=today&fields=ad_name,spend

However, upon making the request, I receive an empty response:
{
  "data": [
  ]
}

I've double-checked the endpoint parameters and they seem correct. Is there something I might be missing or doing wrong in this request that's resulting in an empty response?

Does date_preset=yesterday give you any different result? It might simply be that the data fro this metric isn't available for "today" yet.

No, sadly not, ive tried a bit arround but the latest data ill get is from 26.03.2024 wich is more than a week old wich is not what we need. You have any other idea? Ive read in many posts that they got them for same day or at least yesterday.

If you get data for other date presets, then it can't be an issue of missing permissions, or a wrong request. Maybe try if you get different results, if you specify a time_range instead? If not, then I guess only Facebook can tell you what is actually going on, perhaps file a bug report then.

Yea, i dont think its an Permission Issue. Ive tried thatand same result. also if i try last_month ill get the informatio wanted.
Thanks for your ideas, illcontact Facebook Support and post an Update when Fixed.
